# iText OCR Tesseract 4 working on Windows 10 but not on Windows Server 2016

Tags: itext, ocr, tesseract, itext7, windows-server-2016

We use uses iText OCR with Tesseract 4.
It also works but not on our Windows Server 2016 where we need it.
The error message says that a DLL is missing and the C++ Redistributable should be installed. Sometimes liblept1760 is missing, other times libtesseract400.

We have installed Visual C++ Redistributable and the DLL's are also in the right path.
It works on a freshly set up Windows 10 VM but not on a new Windows Server 2016

Answer (score 0):

found the problem. AVX support was not on, although the processor supports it.
A compatibility setting of my VM has prevented the AVX of the processes from being used

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).